# I want to create a text file with name coming from user and the write in it?

Tags: java, text-files, java-io

I wrote this program for my uni Assignment. The main idea is when ever the addItem is invoked it creates a text file and write order from the user on that file. But how ever it only creates the file but prints nothing on the inside.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.Writer;


public class OrderedFood extends Food {

private int quantity;
private boolean isSet;
private SetDrink setDrink;


public OrderedFood(){
    quantity =  0;
    isSet = false;
    setDrink = null;
}

public OrderedFood(String foodCode, String foodName,boolean isSet, SetDrink    setDrink, int quantity){
    super(foodCode, foodName);
    this.isSet = isSet;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.setDrink = setDrink;
} 

public int  getquantity(){
    return quantity;
}

public void setquantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public boolean getIsSet(){
    return isSet;
}
public void setisSet(boolean isSet){
    this.isSet = isSet;
}
public SetDrink getsetDrink(){
    return setDrink;
}
public void setsetDrink(SetDrink setDrink){
    this.setDrink = setDrink;
}

public void addItem (String foodCode, int TabNum)throws IOException{ 
    clearScreen();  // invoking the clearScreen method


    String filename = Integer.toString(TabNum); 
    try
    {
        //this blocks creates a table by the table num
        File file = new File("/tmp", filename);     
        System.out.println("path=" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        file.createNewFile();

        System.out.println("File created");
    }
    catch(Exception e)  
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to create file");
    }
    try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), "utf-8")))
    {
        writer.write("foodCode"); // this syntax prints the order
        writer.close();
    }

}
public void deleteItem(String foodCode , int TabNum)throws IOException{
    clearScreen();

    String Tab = Integer.toString(TabNum);

    remove(Tab,foodCode);// we just invoke the remove method, which will then remove the item from the .txt file   
}


public static void clearScreen() {  // this method clears the screen.
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
    System.out.flush();  
   }  


 public void remove(String file, String lineToRemove)throws IOException { 

        try {

            File inFile = new File(file);

            if (!inFile.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
                return;
            }

            File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            PrintWriter kap = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            String line = null;


            while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {

                if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {

                    kap.println(line);
                    kap.flush();
                }
            }
            kap.close();
            buff.close();

            if (!inFile.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                return;
            }

            if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
                System.out.println("Could not rename file");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

   }
```

Comment: This code only creates a new file using `file.createNewFile()`. Probably, you should add the code that writes data to the file by yourself.

Comment: yeah but the name of the file  is coming from user, so when i try to use common code for writing to file it asks for the name of the file 
                 `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println("The first line");`

Comment: There is `PrintWriter` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) that accepts `File`.

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2885224/5052976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical mistake when you are creating a file you are not telling the extension also when opening the file for writing you used filename but it contains only the tabnumber not the full path to file use the below code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.Writer;


public class OrderedFood extends Food {

private int quantity;
private boolean isSet;
private SetDrink setDrink;


public OrderedFood(){
    quantity =  0;
    isSet = false;
    setDrink = null;
}

public OrderedFood(String foodCode, String foodName,boolean isSet, SetDrink    setDrink, int quantity){
    super(foodCode, foodName);
    this.isSet = isSet;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.setDrink = setDrink;
} 

public int  getquantity(){
    return quantity;
}

public void setquantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public boolean getIsSet(){
    return isSet;
}
public void setisSet(boolean isSet){
    this.isSet = isSet;
}
public SetDrink getsetDrink(){
    return setDrink;
}
public void setsetDrink(SetDrink setDrink){
    this.setDrink = setDrink;
}

public void addItem (String foodCode, int TabNum)throws IOException{ 
    clearScreen();  // invoking the clearScreen method


    String filename = Integer.toString(TabNum); 
    try
    {
        //this blocks creates a table by the table num
        File file = new File("/tmp", filename);     
        System.out.println("path=" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        file.createNewFile();
        filename = file.getAbsolutePath(); //here the actual address is updated to use later

        System.out.println("File created");
    }
    catch(Exception e)  
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to create file");
    }
    try
    {
      //now here we need that address updated earlier not just the tabnumber
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename, "UTF-8");
      writer.print("food code");
      riter.close();
    }

}
public void deleteItem(String foodCode , int TabNum)throws IOException{
    clearScreen();

    String Tab = Integer.toString(TabNum);

    remove(Tab,foodCode);// we just invoke the remove method, which will then remove the item from the .txt file   
}


public static void clearScreen() {  // this method clears the screen.
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
    System.out.flush();  
   }  


 public void remove(String file, String lineToRemove)throws IOException { 

        try {

            File inFile = new File(file);

            if (!inFile.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
                return;
            }

            File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            PrintWriter kap = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            String line = null;


            while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {

                if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {

                    kap.println(line);
                    kap.flush();
                }
            }
            kap.close();
            buff.close();

            if (!inFile.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                return;
            }

            if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
                System.out.println("Could not rename file");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

   }
```

Comment: a file name extension is not necessary